# Восстановить файлы и БД в Linux

Tags: файлы, база-данных, linux

Добрый вечер!

Помогите советом. Хостер удалил VDS, как можно восстановить файлы и БД, если получится снова заполучить доступ к тому же VDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хмм, задать вопрос хостеру? Найти бекапы?
VDS - это виртуальный сервер, выделенный на уровне ядра системы. Получить доступ к той же области жесткого диска системы, что и была, ИМХО, маловероятно.

Comment: Хостер удалил бэкапы, на компьютере удалили бэкапы...